# Implement different behavior from Module

Tags: perl

I have the following Perl module :

```
package Log;

use strict;
use warnings;

# Packaging
use Exporter;
use vars qw( $VERSION @ISA @EXPORT  );

$VERSION   = '1.0.0';
@ISA       = qw( Exporter );
@EXPORT    = qw(Log_Send);

my %log_g = ('PathDirFileLog' => '/some/path',
             'File'           => undef);

# Init
PrivateLog_OpenFileLog();
print("Do not execute this code unless I want from main.pl\n");

END {
    PrivateLog_CloseFileLog();
}


# Public Functions 

sub Log_Send
{
    my ($message) = @_;

    # Cleaning $message
    $message =~ s/\n+$//g;
    $message =~ s/\n/\*/g;

    print($message);
    print({$log_g{'File'}} $message) if ($log_g{'File'});
    return (1);
}

# Private Functions 

sub PrivateLog_OpenFileLog
{
    my $path = $log_g{'PathDirFileLog'}.'/global.log';

    if (!$log_g{'File'}) {
        if (!open($log_g{'File'}, '>>', $path)) {
            $log_g{'File'} = undef;
            Log_Send("Failed to open '$path' in '>>' mode : $!");
            return (0);
        }
        select((select($log_g{'File'}), $|=1)[0]);
    }
    return (1);
}

sub PrivateLog_CloseFileLog
{
    if ($log_g{'File'}) {
        close($log_g{'File'});
        $log_g{'File'} = undef;
    }
    return (1);
}

1;
```

There is a print that will be executed as soon as I type "use Log;" from any Perl script. Sometime this print has to be here, sometime not (and this situation apply to some other Module I wrote).

Is there a way to "activate" or "desactivate" the print from, per instance, this script ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Log;

Log_Send("Hello world !");
```

It's like "enable/disable" debug on all of module I import, is there a way ?

Edit : I tried to implement my own import sub, but either I lost the @EXPORT mecanism or either I copy/paste source code from Exporter and I don't understand anything. If there is a tutorial for implementing "import" with a mecanism like @EXPORT, I will be happy with that.

Comment: Ideally, under what conditions should the `print` be executed?

Comment: Idealy, I want to set from "main.pl" "something" that will say to all my module "execute this part of code" (code may be in BEGIN, END, sub, anywhere in module). To be more precise, when I wrote a new Perl program, I don't want to print, and when I send the Perl program in production, I want to print. If I can implement such behavior, I can have different behavior from my module if I am in "DEV_MODE" or if I am in "PROD_MODE", the same goes with "DEBUG_ON" and "DEBUG_OFF" (and anything else in my futur Perl script).

Answer (score 1):

Calling `use` implies calling `import` from module's namespace. Make an `import` function, move `print` into it and make it accept flag that signifies that `print` is not needed.

Comment: Creating my own import function make me lose the @EXPORT mecanism.
What you descibe is what I think it will be ideal for me, but I failed to do.

Comment: @Tom's, No, you can use `sub import { ...; goto &Exporter::import; }`. Mind you, your `import` won't be called at all if your script does `use Log qw( );`, so I don't think this is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've indicated in the comments that the factor that decides whether the code should be executed or not is based on the name of the script being executed. I find this particularly odd, and a very poor design, but it is achievable because the path of the script being executed is found in `$0`.

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );

if (basename($0) eq 'main.pl') {
   ...
}
```

---

I think the following interface would be more appropriate:

```
use Carp     qw( );
use Exporter qw( );

sub import {
   my $class = shift;

   my $saw_opts = 0;
   while (@_ && $_[0] =~ /^-/) {
      $saw_opts = 1;
      my $opt = shift(@_);
      if ($opt eq '--debug') {
         ...
      }
      elsif ($opt eq '--') {
         last;
      }
      else {
         Carp::croak("Unknown option $opt\n");
      }
   }

   return if $saw_opts && !@_;

   unshift @_, $class;
   goto &Exporter::import;
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
use Log qw( --debug );
use Log;

  -or-

use Log qw( --debug :DEFAULT );
```

---

On second thought, I take that bad. No need for anything that magical. Just create a sub that does what you want and call it from your script.

```
use Log;
Log::init( debug => 1 );
```

Comment: "You've indicated in the comments that the factor that decides whether the code should be executed or not is based on the name of the script being executed." -> Uh ? Where did I say that ? If you think that, I probably misspell something.

Comment: "On second thought, I take that bad. No need for anything that magical. Just create a sub that does what you want and call it from your script." -> No, because the code can be executed the moment I use "use Log", so your hint with rewrite import seem good to me, thanks.

Comment: I asked "Ideally, under what conditions should the `print` be executed?" And you answered "from main.pl". Mind you, it easy to misunderstand a two word answer. Feel free to clarify,  and I'll adjust